# Calling a void method

Tags: java

Currently I have this code coded as a part of a separate Java class.

```
 public void setSubtotal ()
 {
   subtotal = Validator.getDouble(sc,"Enter subtotal:", 0, 10000);    
 }
```

And I want to call to it from another method. I already have this class instantiated so I can call to it, but I'm not sure how to call to this method since it's a void method.

Comment: `setSubtotal()` ? Setters usually pass in a variable to set though...

Comment: Please get a good book on Java, and read on the basics of methods, their return types, everything. Start with *Bruce Eckel's -Thinking in Java*.

Comment: I'm actually reading Murach's right now and was having an issue understanding part of the assignment I was working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

all you gotta do is

```
 this.setSubtotal();
```

since you're doing it inside the same class

Comment: You can also call `setSubtotal()` instead because `this` is implicit in such method calls.

Comment: I'm actually calling to this method from another class.

Comment: well then just make the class that the setSubtotal() class is in, a new object. MyClass myC = new MyClass();  myC.setSubtotal();

Comment: Now I've got another question. Do I code the get method before or after this? Which I know should look like this:
public double getSubtotal ()
 {
    return subtotal;
 }

and if I were to call to this method to retrieve the subtotal from the set method would I code it like myC.getSubtotal();

Comment: yep, that would be exactly it :)

Comment: I figured that was correct. Which is strange because when I code this line: double discountPercent = Invoice.getDiscountPercent(myC.getSubtotal(), customerType);
It's returning 0 for the subtotal regardless of what value the user enters in the set method

Comment: The reason you're getting 0, is because in the get method, it is returning what the variable subtotal is set for. If you are wanting it to show something that the user enters, all you gotta do is either update the subtotal variable, or create a double to hold the getSubtotal, and pass that....such as double s = myC.getSubtotal(); s = someNumber...; double discountPercent = Invoice.getDiscountPercent(s, customerType);

Comment: How would I go about updating the variable?

Comment: You can create a parameter inside your setSubtotal(), such as setSubtotal(double sub)......then inside the method, do subtotal = sub..and then you can update the subtotal when calling it by doing myC.setSubtotal(//double value to update the value);

Comment: Okay
But I need to use the get method to retrieve the value that is set in the set method as that's part of the assignment I'm working on.

Comment: I have to code the set statment like this: public void setSubtotal ()
 {
    this.subtotal = Validator.getDouble(sc,
                "Enter subtotal:     ", 0, 10000);      
 }

This allows the get method to access it and return in as a double. as a result there is no need for the set to be coded as a double

Comment: Ok, well I'm glad I could help you out!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Y{
   public static void main(String args[]){
       X foo = new X();
       foo.setSubtotal();
   }
}

public class X{
public void setSubtotal ()
 {
   subtotal = Validator.getDouble(sc,"Enter subtotal:", 0, 10000);    

 }
}
```